# iOS Add BLE Characteristic

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I have a peripheral app running and I'm trying to put a simple string on a characteristic. The peripheral looks like this:

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral{
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        _notifyUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"E098FDEF-B82C-43F1-8BFB-18757743BA10"];
        _notificationCharacteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:_notifyUUID
                                                                         properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify
                                                                              value:nil
                                                                        permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

        _shareService = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:_serviceUUID primary:YES];


        [_shareService setCharacteristics:@[_notificationCharacteristic]];

        [_pMgr addService:_shareService];

        [self startAdvertising];

    }
}

-(void) peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveReadRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request {
    request.value =
        [@"Some Data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
  [_pMgr respondToRequest:request withResult:CBATTErrorSuccess];
}
```

However when I try to see that data on the characteristic and log it out, I'm seeing nil for the value:

```
2015-09-24 12:57:36.875 BLEScanner[533:43084] Discovered characteristic <CBCharacteristic: 0x17546740, UUID = E098FDEF-B82C-43F1-8BFB-18757743BA10, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = NO>
```

Scanner source:

```
-(void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog( @"didDiscoverService" );

    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered service %@", service);
        if( service == peripheral.services.lastObject ) {
            [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service
             error:(NSError *)error {

    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"Discovered characteristic %@", characteristic);
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing as I've been going through the documentation on Apple's site for using BLE (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html)

Comment: What do you mean "see the data on the characteristic"? Where? How? When you discover a characteristic, you have to read its value (readValue), or set notify.

Comment: Updated with the scanner source. I'm displaying the characteristic in that output I posted earlier, but a portion of it is nil and I'm not seeing the data I'm posting to it.

Comment: `for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:characteristic];}`, and look at the `CBPeripheralDelegate` method `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:`

Comment: Ah there we go, getting an error for '2015-09-24 13:18:12.871 BLEScanner[557:46640] Reading is not permitted.' Thanks.